# Shedulig service invokation in nifi

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, apache-nifi

I have one GenerateFlowFile processor where  I have 2 attributes userId(equals=1) and parameter (equals=5) , I have service which should give me  repsonse for each userId  from(1 to 5) so i need to call it 5 times ,what i want is to genreate 5 flowfile in execute script to invoke service 5 times with related  id I have tried this  code  below  but it doesn't work for me  could you give me any advice  what should i do ?

```
var OutputStreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

Date.prototype.isValid = function ()
{
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === "[object Date]") && !isNaN(this.getTime());
};

var flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null)


    var userId= flowFile.getAttribute('userId') //equals 1
var parameter=flowFile.getAttribute('parameter')//equals5
var  i=0;

while(parameter<i) {
    var flowFile = session.get();
    if (flowFile != null)
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', userId + '_' + parameter);


    flowFile = session.write(flowFile,
        new OutputStreamCallback(function (outputStream) {
            outputStream.write(0)
        }));

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    userId++;
    parameter--;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is  there any native  nifi processor  i should use in this case?

Comment: The while(parameter < i) should be reversed since parameter is 5 and i is 0, also you already obtained a flow file at the beginning from session.get() so inside the loop you probably want to create new flow files with session.create(), and then remove the original one at the end of the code using session.remove() or transfer it to an original relationship

Comment: Thank you I  have edited my code  and  now it  works

Answer (score 0):

```
var OutputStreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

Date.prototype.isValid = function ()
{
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === "[object Date]") && !isNaN(this.getTime());
};


var flowFile=session.get()
if (flowFile != null) {
    var userId = flowFile.getAttribute('userId')
    var parameter = flowFile.getAttribute('parameter')
    var i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<=parameter;i++) {
        var flowfile1=session.create();

        userId++;
        flowfile1 = session.putAttribute(flowfile1, 'filename', userId);


        flowfile1 = session.write(flowfile1,
            new OutputStreamCallback(function (outputStream) {
                outputStream.write(0)
            }));



        session.transfer(flowfile1, REL_SUCCESS)

        parameter--;
    }

    session.remove(flowFile)
}
```